# How can I check if IP numbers are in the same subnet with Perl?

Tags: perl, ip

How can I check if IP numbers are in the same subnet with Perl?

Can I use [NetAddr::IP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/NetAddr-IP)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like the [Net::Subnet Perl module](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Subnet) would do this. There's an example at that link I gave. If you don't want to use CPAN to get the module, both Debian and Ubuntu have a libnet-subnets-perl package.

Comment: As of 11/2012, Net::Subnets does not exist on CPAN but there is a Net::Subnet that should do it. I prefer NetAddr::IP for that sort of thing though.

Answer (score 9):

You could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use NetAddr::IP;

my $first  = NetAddr::IP->new('10.0.0.1/24');
my $second = NetAddr::IP->new('10.0.0.5/32');

if ($second->within($first)) {
    printf "%s is within %s\n", $second, $first;
} else {
    printf "%s is not within %s\n", $second, $first;
}
```